# How to show this Knockout observable on the html?

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to populate this Knockout object data on the html. But it doesnt show up on the ui.

I tried foreach statements. I dont want to create individual variables as the input content is going to be dynamic.

View model:

```
public jsonData: KnockoutObservable<any> = ko.observable({
        "fruits": [],
        "cars": [],
    });


    var fruitsArr = [];
        var carsArr = [];

        fruitsArr.push("Mango");
        fruitsArr.push("pineapple");
        carsArr.push("ford");
        carsArr.push("honda");

         that.jsonData({
                cars: carsArr,
                fruits: fruitsArr,
            });
```

HTML:

```html
 <!-- ko foreach: jsonData.cars -->
<p class="SummaryHeading"><span data-bind="text: $data"></span></p>

<!-- /ko -->
```

No error messages. But does not show the desired data

Comment: jsonData is observable, so i think you should use ``ko foreach: jsonData().cars``

Comment: @HuaTrung please post that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jsonData` is an observable. So, you should use

```
<!-- ko foreach: jsonData().cars -->
```

Comment: @RAVINDHARA.R. You can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289255) by clicking on the grey checkmark on the left.